# write.csv function does not work in .Rprofile

Tags: r, startup

I was trying to use `write.csv` in `.Rprofile` to always keep a csv file with my current packages (I do not want to always update this list manually. However, I got the error message that `write.csv` does not exist. So I assume, this function is somehow not compatible with R Startup or not loaded by then?. The command worked fine when I ran it manually. Are there any other options or can I somehow circumvent this problem?

Kind regards

Comment: try `utils::write.csv(...)` ?

Comment: Probably worth showing how you are trying to do this e.g. `.Last <- function(){
  write.csv(installed.packages()[,"Package"], "files.csv")
}` seems to work

Comment: Wow, this just worked. Nice and easy answer. ```utils::write.csv``` was all it took.